# how to generate a list quickly iterating a file

Tags: list, f#

Me coming from a c# and python background, feels there must be a better way to read a file and populate a classic F# list. But then I know that a f# list is immutable. There must be an alternative using a `List<string>` object and calling its `Add` method.

So far what I have at hand:

```
let ptr = new StreamReader("stop-words.txt")
let lst = new List<string>()
let ProcessLine line =
    match line with
    | null -> false
    | s -> 
        lst.Add(s)
        true
while ProcessLine (ptr.ReadLine()) do ()
```

If I were to write the similar stuff in python I'd do something like:

```
[x[:-1] for x in open('stop-words.txt')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution

```
    System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename) |> List.ofArray
```

Although you can write a recursive function

```
let processline fname =
    let file = new System.IO.StreamReader("stop-words.txt")
    let rec dowork() =
        match file.ReadLine() with
        |null -> []
        |t -> t::(dowork())
    dowork()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read all lines from a file, you can just use `ReadAllLines`. The method returns the data as an array, but you can easily turn that into F# list using `List.ofArray` or process it using the functions in the `Seq` module:

```
open System.IO

File.ReadAllLines("stop-words.txt")
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to read all the contents into memory, you can use `File.ReadLines` which reads the lines lazily.